# Porting a program from MATLAB to Java?

Tags: java, matlab

I'm developing a program in MATLAB, however at some point I want to move away from command line input and output and create a GUI and make the program standalone.

I have read that you can compile MATLAB code into Java, would it then be possible to wrap up these Java modules and add in my own GUI code, eventually creating a standalone executable?

Answer (score 0):

Converting MATLAB code to Java is possible. Check this out: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/ug/create-a-java-class-from-matlab-code.html

As far as I know, this is not a license free feature and I can imagine that this will cost  a few dollars...

I was recently faced with a similar problem. I decided to convert the matlab code manually to Java... However, this was only possible because the source code was not too huge.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are three ways:

1. You can use the BuilderJA (license required) which requires Matlab MCR to be installed on the arget system (Free runtime environment)
2. Use some automation interface which calls Matlab in the background. Matlab needs to be installed on the target system
3. You generate C++ code from your matlab code and put it into a library. Generating C++ code is not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile your m-files into single jar. You need Matlab Compiler. There you pick m-files to compile and fill jar name etc.

In order to use this library in your program you also need javabuilder.jar. You can find this in your Matlab directory or external MATLAB Compiler Runtime.

And few extra notes:

1. You have to use MATLAB Compiler Runtime (just javabuilder.jar) from the same Matlab version you compile yours m-files.
2. From Java side Matlab structures (cells, arrays) are just Object so you will have to cast hard (debugger can be rally helpful to see what types there really are)
3. For compilation time it may be necessary to set JAVA_HOME or MATLAB_JAVA (by trial and error) for java version that Matlab use (command 'version -java' inside Matlab)